# matlab append different values of the same variable on button click

Tags: matlab

So I am doing this in matlab app designer, I have a variable `x` which changes on every button click, I would like to add every value of `x` to an array to find the average. Say on the first click, `x` is `10`, on the second, `x` is `2` and on the 3rd `x` is `9`, I would like an array, values, to be equal to `[10 2 9]`. Every time I have tried, it just ends up containing the most recent `x` value. Below is what I have tried.

```
function GenerateButtonPushed(app, event)
x = (randi[1 30]);
values = [];
values(end+1) = x;
average = mean(values)
```

I can see what the problem is, every time I press the button, it resets the array to be empty, but I do not know how to get around this. Suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this with a [persistent variable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html):

```matlab
function GenerateButtonPushed(app, event)
x = (randi[1 30]);
persistent values % initialized to [] on first call
values(end+1) = x;
average = mean(values)
```

`values` will be reset every time you do `clear all` or `clear functions` or `clear GenerateButtonPushed` or anything else that removes the function from memory. You cannot modify the variable in any other way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store your values somehwere other than the callback function.
One way is to use `setappdata` and `getappdata`.

```
function GenerateButtonPushed(app, event)
    x = (randi[1 30]);
    values = getappdata(app.Parent, 'myvalues'); % Get values from the app
    values(end+1) = x;
    setappdata(app.Parent, 'myvalues', values); % Put the updated values back
    average = mean(values)
```

Somewhere in your app startup you'll need to initialise the array with something like, `setappdata(app_fig, 'myvalues', [])`.

See examples [here](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html)

Note I'd suggest reading about the "scope" of variables within functions so you understand why they don't persist.